# Laravel join table with json using MariaDB

Tags: php, json, laravel, mariadb

PHP 7.2

MariaDB 10.3.11

Laravel 5.5.45

https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-vouchers/issues/10

I am using this package. Inside the `vouchers` table have a field `data` 
which is store array / json data.

The `vouchers` table inside the `data` field type is `TEXT`.

https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-vouchers/blob/master/database/migrations/create_vouchers_table.php.stub

E.g

`{"customer_id":1,"customer_name":"Shiro","message":"Birthday Voucher"}`

Voucher Table:-

```
+-----+-----------+-----------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | code      | model_type      | model_id | data                                                                     | expires_at          | created_at          | updated_at          |
+-----+-----------+-----------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 170 | 1111-1112 | App\VoucherType |        2 | {"customer_id":"1","customer_name":"Shiro","message":"Birthday Voucher"} | 2019-04-30 23:59:59 | 2019-03-20 04:58:12 | 2019-03-20 04:58:12 |
+-----+-----------+-----------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Customer Table

```
+------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| id   | user_name                                    | email                |
+------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| 1    | AMAZON BEAUTY SUPPLY - BEAUTIFUL LADYGAGA HA | beautifyfu@gmail.com |
+------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

I would like to join with my `customers` table.

I tried `https://github.com/ybr-nx/laravel-mariadb` , but still can't directly join the table.

Any idea how to join two table and one of the table using json field?

Comment: What is the datatype of `data`?

Comment: Is it necessary to join customers table with your vouchers table via json? what you can do is to store customer_id in another column in voucher's table while saving your json and then create simple join.

Comment: @revo data type is `TEXT`, I added the link.  @Osama Alvi, the reason why I didn't add the extra column because I try not to change their database structure and they put it like that for reason. I think mostly I will create another field, no need waste time... but I am thinking to have better idea to improve my coding

Comment: hi @Shiro, did you ever get this one working?